How does Spark read a single large splittable file? (logical block and physical block)
I have a question about the behavior when reading splittable large files in Spark.
I understand that files like Parquet or ORC are splittable.
I have also confirmed that when reading a large Parquet file, multiple tasks are created to read it in parallel.
Furthermore, I understand that processing engines like Spark and MapReduce minimize Network IO by aligning the physical storage block size with the logical processing unit.
files like Parquet or ORC are binary files with magic numbers and metadata embedded inside.
For example, Avro files contain metadata in the header, while Parquet files store metadata in the footer.
Let's say we have a large 1GB file, and the HDFS block size is 256MB. The file will be divided into blocks like [256MB, 256MB, 256MB, 256MB] and stored in HDFS.
However, since one of these blocks contains the footer, I believe each physical block will be stored in the following manner
   Phy    Log

|------|------| Magic Number
|      |------|
|      |      |
|------|      |
|      |------|
|      |      |
|------|      |
|      |------|
|      |      |
|------|      |
|      |------|
|      |      | Footer, Magic Number
|------|------| 

This suggests that the logical blocks are different from the physical blocks.
Upon inspecting several blocks, I found that only one block contains metadata. Therefore, most tasks need to read two blocks.
However, many documents state that each task reads one file. And indeed, in Spark tasks, I've observed that exactly one block is read.
How is this possible?
I've searched through numerous books and blogs related to MapReduce and Spark regarding splittable files, but I couldn't find information about their actual behavior.
thank you
